# What does "腰抜ける" mean?

Tags: translation

Was browsing through japanes IG pages and saw this post https://www.instagram.com/p/Bp61vFtAdFo/?hl=ja

Someone left this comment.

> ボヘミアンラプソディ！！
>   腰抜けるぐらいよかった！！

Haven't found what it means on any online dictionary but I did find other uses. There's a whole hashtag of it in twitter, it looks like.

For example, there's this one.

> まずい聞こえたか。
>   恥ずかしい。
>   腰抜ける

To my knowledge, the first 2 would translate as "Did it sound bad? This is embarassing." No idea about the last one, though. 腰 and 抜ける seems to have a lot of possible meanings in the dictionary.

Comment: Have you tried 「腰**が**抜ける」 in a dictionary? eg http://jisho.org/search/腰が抜ける

Comment: That's right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> まずい聞こえたか。 恥ずかしい。 腰抜ける

I would translate this into something like this.

> Oh Jesus, anybody heard it (what I said or what I did)? Freaking embarrassing. Scares the shit out of me.

But I don't know the exact situation the person is in. Not 100% sure.